# Type safe Effects for the Actions passed from createAction method in ngrx 11+

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, typescript-typings, ngrx-effects

After reading several blogs details the usage and benefits of using `createAction`/`createEffect` (compare to classic `@Effect` and `implements Action`) which enables IDE to imply typing from the `createAction` method without declaring types again.

But what if we need to explicitly declare e.g. while combining other observables before pipe down to the stream?

For example (for full `createEffect`, see below),

```
this.actions$.pipe(ofType(FooActions.getFoo)).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(bar$),
      map(
        ([foo, bar]: [
          ReturnType<typeof FooActions.getFoo>,
          Bar[]
        ]) => {
          ...
          return FooActions.loadFoo(...);
        }
      )
    );
```

Example above shows the need of explicitly declare the type of `getFoo` action. Since when adding the second observable `bar$` (implementation omitted) to the tuple sometimes we need to know the type of *bar* for convenience of programming.

Now, the typing of first item down the pipe couldn't be omitted, but how we are able to declare it? Is my code correct to copy the **action creation function name** and adding **typeof**, then wrapped by a **ReturnType**? (`ReturnType<typeof FooActions.getFoo>`)

It looks chunky and anti-pattern at a glance in this way.

Further thinking is, how we declare the created Effect type (`onLoadFooBar$`)?

```
const onLoadFooBar$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(ofType(FooActions.getFoo)).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(bar$),
      map(
        ([foo, bar]: [
          ReturnType<typeof FooActions.getFoo>,
          Bar[]
        ]) => {
          ...
          return FooActions.loadFoo(...);
        }
      )
    );
});
```

Is it to be `onLoadFooBar$: ReturnType<typeof FooActions.loadFoo> = createEffect(() => {`

I found the `union` method wrapped the ReturnType but it is expanded to cover more than the typing I need at this place.

Answer (score 1):

Manually adding types shouldn't be needed.
Even if you add other observables to the mix.
If you have a reproduction, I'm happy to take a look.

Side note: try `concatLatestFrom` instead of `withLatestFrom`: https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/prefer-concat-latest-from.md

Comment: other observables which is not created by store action creator but something else, may be needed to add types for the typescript compiler.